# How can STM32 HID send a packet less than 64 Byte?

Tags: c, usb, stm32, hid

I am using STM32F103 with "STM32_USB-FS-Device_Lib_V4.0.0" to send data to PC. The send function in STM32 is:

```
void USB_Send(unsigned char *p,u8 len)
{
    UserToPMABufferCopy(p, GetEPTxAddr(ENDP1), len);
    SetEPTxCount(ENDP1, len); 
    SetEPTxValid(ENDP1);
    while(GetEPTxStatus(ENDP1)!=EP_TX_NAK);
}
```

But what's strange is when len=64， data received properly by a C# program that I write and a debug tool that I download. But when len<64 nothing can be received. I tried "Bus Hound" a USB packet sniffer, and the packet that less than 64 can be logged by the sniffer, but the readdata function in my program was never entered.

I also tried to change the value of MaxPacketSize in ConfigDescriptor and REPORT_COUNT in ReportDescriptor in STM32 program, but they doesn't work.

Does HID limit that the length of one packet must be a certain value, if length is less than the value, extra data must be filled at the end of packet until the length equals certain value?

Can someone give me some help or hint, thank you!

---

Complement:

I have tried to send two 32Bytes packets without delay, and it didn't work.

Here is my C# receive code:

```
//Init code:
HIDP_CAPS capabilities = new HIDP_CAPS();
int hidCapsSucsess = HidP_GetCaps(ptrToPreParsedData, ref capabilities);  //HidP_GetCaps is a win API
SafeFileHandle handle_read = CreateFile(devicePath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);  //CreateFile is a win API
FileStream FS_read = new FileStream(handle_read, FileAccess.ReadWrite, capabilities.OutputReportByteLength, false);
//...
//Receive code:
public byte[] read()
{
    byte[] readBuf = new byte[capabilities.OutputReportByteLength];
    FS_read.Read(readBuf, 0, capabilities.OutputReportByteLength);
    return readBuf;
}
```

I tried to change the value of REPORT_COUNT of output in ReportDescriptor in STM32. Breakpoint debugging shows "capabilities.OutputReportByteLength" was changed but what's strange is it equals REPORT_COUNT+1. Furthermore, when the "capabilities.OutputReportByteLength" is less than 65, an error occurred:"*The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation*" in "FS_read.Read".

Comment: If you *can* detect the packets on USB bus, you seem to look at the bad end of the bus - have you considered your C# program not reading the data correctly? What if the latter blocks until having received (at least) 64 bytes?

Comment: Those old full of bugs ST libraries are full of surprises. What is the problem of setting the 64 bytes transfer if the USB FS frame is 64 bytes?

Comment: May be minimum packet size in the windows size is 64 bytes. I mean windows size waits until the data received is 64 bytes and then only gives whole 64 bytes to user application. Can you try sending 32 bytes and 32 bytes in two transactions without significant delay between them? Check whether you receive those two transactions as single 64 byte chunk in your windows program?